# Remove margin from empty element

Tags: html, css

I'm having a lot of problems to remove the margin on this div in the picture. I'm generating a lot of divs in a loop but some of them are empty, although the margin is still applied to the element with height:0. How can I remove the margin on the empty elements using CSS?

Note: Unfortunately, I do not know which tiles are empty when the divs are generated. Only the children have conditions, so they can be generated with empty children and I end up with an empty div with margins.

[image: problem to fix]

```
.tile {
float: left;
width: 24%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 10px 0.25%;}
```

Comment: try, like, `display: none`. That tends to do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

*Try This:*

```
.tile:empty{
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
.tile, .tile1 {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px 0.25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.tile:empty{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>With Empty Selector</h1>
<div class="tile">Not Empty</div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile">Not Empty</div>
<br><br>
<h1>Without Empty Selector</h1>
<div class="tile1">Not empty</div>
<div class="tile1"></div>
<div class="tile1">Not Empty</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know which tiles are empty when the divs are generated. Only the children have conditions so they can be generated and then the children are empty and I end up with an empty div.

Comment: No. I have 10 divs. Some of them are empty, some have content inside. I want to remove the margin from the empty divs. The height is equal to 0 but the margin is still applied. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: @Diogo123, when you use css style,it detect empty divs automatically.

Comment: you try my post?

Comment: It didn't work. All the divs have some ng-if comments inside

Answer (score 1):

When you generate, check that if it does not have a value, then do not generate that div.

Comment: I can't do that. Only the children have conditions.